# set a form field as None value before saving it

Tags: python, django

I have a model field like this:

```
lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=16,null=True,blank=True)
```

In my views I need to set it as `None` before saving the form and somehow I can't figure out how!
it raises this error:

```
IntegrityError at /meeting/create-meeting/
NOT NULL constraint failed: meeting_meeting.lat
```

How can I solve it?

```
 meeting=form.save(commit=False)
 meeting.number_of_member = len(form.cleaned_data['members_email'].split(','))
 members = form.cleaned_data['members_email']
 if "is_virtual" in request.POST:
     meeting.lat = None
     meeting.lng = None
                       
 else:
     meeting.lat= round(form.cleaned_data['lat'],14)
     meeting.lng = round(form.cleaned_data['lng'],14)
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: pls fix your indentation.

Comment: null = True in your models should be ok. did you makemigrations/migrate ?